# How to store cookies instantly and permanently?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, cookies

I'm developing a website in MVC and I'm setting/updating cookies like this on my action method:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie_name");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
cookie.Value = cookieValue;
Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

Now, this works just fine. But, if I kill Chrome right after this, the next time I access the website, the cookie is not there (or it has an older value and not the last one).
I've checked the 'Cookies' file stored in 'C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default' and it seems it is only updated approximately once every minute or so. It looks like new cookies are all stored in RAM for a while and then saved as a batch to the hard drive.

I've also tried to set the cookie directly with javascript (using js-cookie library) but the outcome was the same:

```
Cookies.set('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', { expires: 30 });
```

Is there a way to store cookies instantly and permanently?

Comment: Do you mean "permanently" as in "even if the user clears their browser cookies"?

Comment: @GibralterTop it's not a session cookie, I set expiration date to 30 days from now.

Comment: @alex No, sorry, that is misleading. I mean that it shouldn't disappear if chrome closed unproperly (kill process or restart PC) immediately after the cookie is set.

Comment: `localStorage` should be sync...

Comment: That's interesting. You are indeed setting a persistent cookie, which should survive the end of the current browser session. If it's not doing that, then that would be a bug in Chrome. I suggest taking it up with the Chromium team: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @dandavis I thought about localStorage, but it's not the cleanest solution for what I want to implement. I'd really like to use cookies.

Comment: well you can use both, moving the localStorage to cookies onready if needed, just as a backup.

Comment: @dandavis I'll keep that solution in mind as last resort, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for the suggestion. I've submitted a ticket.